# I'm trying to filter a RecyclerView based on the object's value

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

so I got here a block of code which gets all my objects from Firebase/Firestore and set them in my RecyclerView:

```
public void getFromDatabase(String sortBy, String collectionPath, int minPrice, int maxPrice) {

    Query query = db.collection(collectionPath).orderBy(sortBy, Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Gpu> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Gpu>()
            .setQuery(query, Gpu.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Gpu, GpuHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GpuHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Gpu gpu) {

            holder.textViewModel.setText(gpu.getModel());
            holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getPrice()));
            holder.textViewBench.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getBench()));
            holder.textViewValue.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getValue()));
            holder.textViewType.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getType()));
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public GpuHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.gpulist_layout, parent, false);

            return new GpuHolder(view);
        }

    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.startListening();
    gpuRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

As you can tell, the `minPrice` and `maxPrice` does nothing yet, basically, I wanted to make something like "if object price is higher than minPrice and lower than maxPrice, put it to the RecyclerView, otherwise, go back and repeat".

By the way, this is how the app currently looks like, the filters/sorting here work:

[image: grafika]

I'm only stuck on filtering based on price, so far i've tried putting the if statement like this (minPrice is set to 70 and max to 600):

```
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GpuHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Gpu gpu) {

            if (gpu.getPrice() > minPrice && gpu.getPrice() < maxPrice) {

                holder.textViewModel.setText(gpu.getModel());
                holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getPrice()));
                holder.textViewBench.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getBench()));
                holder.textViewValue.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getValue()));
                holder.textViewType.setText(String.valueOf(gpu.getType()));
            }
        }
```

But I can't do an `else {continue;}` since this is not a for loop. So it does weird things like this:

[image]

for some reason, when I scroll down and up, these "TextView" objects disappear, and my "sort descending/ascending" does not work anymore.

if it may help, this is how i do the descend/ascend, i just reverse/unreverse the layout : `LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);`

so yeah, anyone got any idea how to do this? if there's any info I should provide please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

I would have when the different sorting selections are picked they call different methods and use the Collections.sort(options, new Comparator();

```
public void sortByPrice(){
Collections.sort(options, new Comparator<Gpu>() {
        public int compare(Gpu gpu1, Gpu gpu2) {
          // do your comparison of prices here 
    });

 adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

On the “onClickListener() or whatever event listener you use for when they select the filter they want is where you’re to put the method call

For sorting this will work, but for an actual filter what you will need to do is use a method like this

```
public void sortByPrice(){
ArrayList<Gpu> filteredList = new    ArrayList();
for(Gpu gpu : options){
     if(//whatever your requirements are){
   filteredList.add(gpu);
}
}

 adapter.setItems(filteredList);
 adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: i don't understand how do you add this, i'm a newbie on coding in general, can you please be more spesific? do i add this inside or outside my getFromDatabase method?

Comment: and how come there is only 2 closing brackets? is what you typed correct?

Comment: and how do i delete the object which does not satisfy the price filter/requirement?

Comment: i'm trying to "filter" by the way, not sort, or is that the same thing?